# ResolveUrl with variable getting "Too many characters in character literal" error

Tags: javascript

All the examples I've seen for using ResolveUrl have a literal path in them like shown here:

```
window.location='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx") %>'
```

However, I have parsed the URL I wish to redirect to from the menu context of an Infragistics WebDataMenu and I'm trying to pas that variable into the ResolveUrl. The function I'm using is here:

```
    function menuMain_ItemSelected(sender, e) {
        var menuContext = e._context.adr;
        var intPartOfMenuContext = parseInt(menuContext);
        if (menuContext !== intPartOfMenuContext.toString()) {
            var selectedURL = e._props[2]._element.childNodes[0].href;
            window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl(' + selectedURL + ') %>';
        } 
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting a "Too many characters in character literal" error on the ResolveUrl line.

An Example of what selectedURL has is here:

```
"http://localhost:52168/ITRequest/Person.aspx?MenuTitle=Users"
```

FYI: Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is make the WebDataMenu work such that users click on it to open the menu and then click again to select and redirect to the selected page. Apparently however, if ActivateOnHover="False" (which I need to have) the control only responds to arrowing down and pressing Enter once the menu is opened. So, if I'm missing something more obvious, I'm all ears.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a case of taking it one step too far.  The solution I found was to simply remove ResolveUrl from the line altogether, leaving the line below, which worked for me.

```
window.location = selectedURL;
```

Comment: This method will only work when you have the full URL. In which case, calling `ResolveUrl` doesn't make any sense. The purpose of `ResolveURL` is to determine the full URL when given a relative URL like `~/Account/Login.aspx`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for a better reference, here's how you can correctly accomplish what you were trying to do:

```
function menuMain_ItemSelected(sender, e){
    var selectedURL = /*Your code goes here*/;
    window.location.href = ResolveUrl(selectedURL);
}

function ResolveUrl(url) {
    var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
    if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}
```